# How to pass command to the server using ssh2-promise module node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh, async-await, node-modules

I have the following code:

```
var sshPromise=require('ssh2-promise');
var x={
    host:'host',
    username:'username',
    password:'mypassword'
};
var ssh=new sshPromise(x);

ssh.connect().then(()=>{
    console.log('connected...');
});

//Get a shell session
ssh.shell().then((socket) => {
    socket.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(data.toString());

    })
    //Can write to socket 
    //console.log('here<--'); 
    socket.write('my password');// <----sending password to enter the server
});
```

what is trying to do here is I'm creating a shell session after connecting to a server.After connecting  it asks me password to access the server and i want to send my password but it does nothing.

I did a little debugging by adding `console.log('here<--')` and realised that it gets printed right at the start before the **data** arrives, meaning the `socket.write('my password')` gets executed before the data arrives.

I can't figure out how to solve this. Can anyone please help me.

EDIT:

```
const socket = await ssh.shell();

const data = await new Promise(resolve => socket.on('data', resolve));
socket.write('my password\n');
//to fetch next shell output
const data_1= await new Promise(resolve => socket.on('data', resolve));
```

is there any way to call use the data multiple times rather than creating a new promise everytime i need to get output from the shell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `async` / `await` you can wait for the "data" event to fire using a `Promise`:

```
const socket = await ssh.shell();

const data = await new Promise(resolve => socket.on('data', resolve));

socket.write('my password');
```

That way, `socket.write` is only called after you have `data`.

---

If this needs to be used multiple times, you could define a function:

```
const waitForDataAsync = socket => new Promise(resolve => socket.on('data', resolve));
```

Then use like this:

```
const socket = await ssh.shell();

const data = await waitForDataAsync(socket);
socket.write('my password\n');
//to fetch next shell output
const data_1 = await waitForDataAsync(socket);
```

Comment: Okay so it works perfect and here the shell output is stored in `data`. Now I pass a command to the server using **socket.write**. To get that output I did this:                                                                              `const data_1 = await new Promise(resolve => socket.on('data', resolve));`                                                                                       which kinda feels wrong to me but just to clarify, Is there any way to use this **data** without creating any new promise next time if i want to fetch new output ?

Comment: @DarthCucumber Can you add your new code to the question?

Comment: You could just pass a callback if nothing else relies on the new data, but if your next stage needs to wait for the response, using Promises will be much more readable in my opinion. You could even wrap the logic in a function; see my edit.